# EmEditorで特定の拡張子に対しては最初から、そのままアスキーモードかバイナリモードで開くように設定できますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
開くときにいちいち確認をとってくるのではなく、そのままクリックしたらアスキーモードで開ける設定です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [メニューのツール->設定の関連付け]から拡張子毎の関連付けを変更できます。
  標準ではバイナリー用の設定はないので、バイナリー用の設定を先に作ることになるでしょう、
  手順の例として...
  [メニューのツール->設定の選択->設定の定義]で設定の定義ダイアログを開いて、
  [設定: Text] を選択して [コピー]
  (これは、大雑把な設定を引き継ぎたいから)
  設定名'Text2'を 'Bin' などと改名して
  ・'Bin' の [プロパティ] を開いて
  ・[ファイル] の
  　　開く時のエンコード: バイナリ
  　　規定の拡張子: bin
  など目的に合った設定に変更。
  　
  そして、[メニューのツール->設定の関連付け]から目的の拡張子に
  [新規作成]か既存の設定を変更して上の、設定名'Bin'に関連付けます。
- 他にコマンドラインスイッチで
  emeditor /c "設定名" ファイルパス
  としてショートカットやバッチファイルなどから指定できます。
  この場合はファイル単位ですけどね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解しました。御厚意､感謝しております。

Comment: ありがとうございます。このサイトのベストアンサーの仕組みを理解してませんでした。きょう行いました。認識不足で申し訳ございませんでした。よろしくお願いいたします